# How to configure react-hooks/exhaustive-deps additionalHooks for modules?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have a `useCustomHook` defined in a module that I want to include in the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` check. I've tried adding it to the `additionalHooks` option, but that doesn't work if I use a qualified import.

```
import * as MyMod from 'my_module'
.
.
.
const value = MyMod.useCustomHook(() => depA + missingDep, [depA])
```

I've tried using a regex for anything ending in this hook name:

```
      "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": [ "warn", {
         "additionalHooks": '(.*\.useCustomHook)'
      }],
```

But it doesn't match. I've tried with and without a `.`, without the prefix `(useCustomHook)`, and few other module specific names. I can't get any of them to match the use.

How should I write the regex to match the use of the hook via a module name?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer of this question 

Comment: where you put that config?

Comment: I need this too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't find a solution. I believe we modified the code to add in additional names to check.

Answer (score -1):

please use it like this:

```
 "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": [ "warn", {
     "additionalHooks": '(useCustomHook)'
  }],
```